# ClassCastException on custom SurfaceView

Tags: android, surfaceview, classcastexception

i've got a big problem since a few days:
When I try to bind the surfaceview on the layout and my custom surfaceview, i get a ClassCastException from my custom surfaceview.

here is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     waveform =(WaveFormView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
}
class WaveFormView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {        
    public WaveFormView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
        _dthread = new DrawingThread(getHolder(), this);
        setFocusable(true);
        paintP.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paintP.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paintP.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paintT.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paintT.setStrokeWidth(1);
        paintT.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
        for (int i=0;i<_athread.buffer.length-pas;i+=pas){
            canvas.drawLine(i, 150-_athread.buffer[i], i+pas, 150-_athread.buffer[i+pas], paintP);
        }
        canvas.drawText("FPS:  " + String.valueOf(FPS), 0, 10, paintT);
        //canvas.drawText("tmp:  " + tmp, 0, 20, paintT);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        _dthread.setRunning(true);
        _dthread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // simply copied from sample application LunarLander:
        // we have to tell thread to shut down & wait for it to finish, or else
        // it might touch the Surface after we return and explode
        boolean retry = true;
        _dthread.setRunning(false);
        while (retry) {
            try {
                _dthread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // we will try it again and again...
            }
        }
    }
}

class DrawingThread extends Thread {
    private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
    private WaveFormView _waveformview;
    private boolean _run = false;

    public DrawingThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, WaveFormView waveformview) {
        _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        _waveformview = waveformview;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        _run = run;
    }

    public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
        return _surfaceHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Canvas c;
        long startMs=System.currentTimeMillis();
        int frameCounter=0;
        while (_run) {
            c = null;
            frameCounter++;
            if (System.currentTimeMillis()-startMs>1000){
                startMs = System.currentTimeMillis();
                FPS = frameCounter;
                frameCounter=0;
            }
            try {
                c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                    _waveformview.onDraw(c);
                }
            } finally {
                // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                // inconsistent state
                if (c != null) {
                    _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I replace:

> setContentView(R.layout.main);

with this:

> setContentView(new WaveFormView (this));

...it works perfectly !
 But, I need to have buttons besides.

here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:padding="0dip" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/content">
         <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tvdebug" android:text="Debug" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>
         <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/surfaceView1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></SurfaceView>
</LinearLayout>
```

If someone have the solution it would me a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe `R.id.surfaceView1` is not declared as `WaveFormView` but as `SurfaceView`? Try declare it specifically, otherwise this is illegal casting indeed.

`WaveFormView` is a `SurfaceView`, but a `SurfaceView` is not necessarily a `WaveFormView`.

You can use your own view in the layout xml, by specifying the class name (`<path.to.WaveFormView` instead of `<SurfaceView...`)

For example:

```
<view class = "com.mypath.WaveFormView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
    android:layout_above="@id/auto_scrollview"
/>
```

OR

```
<com.mypath.WaveFormView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"
    android:layout_above="@id/auto_scrollview"
/>
```

If this class is an inner class, as seemed from your question, then use:

```
<com.mypath.OUTERCLASSNAME$WaveFormView
```

## EDIT

Since this class is needed to be shown from outside your class, and be loaded not from instance but statically, you need to `public static` to its declaration, e.g.:

```
public static class WaveFormView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
```

Comment: Where ? in the layout xml ? Programaticly ?

Comment: in the layout xml, (as I wrote in the answer)

Comment: Eclipse says;The following classes could not be found:
- WaveFormView

Comment: I get "java.lang.LinkageError: loader (instance of  com/android/ide/eclipse/adt/internal/resources/manager/ProjectClassLoader): attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/blueproject/BlueProject$WaveFormView""
from Eclipse

Comment: 1. clean your project and try again. 2. if not working - post your modified xml and the relevant code lines.

Comment: <LinearLayout
     android:layout_weight="1" 
     android:padding="0dip" 
     android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent" 
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:id="@+id/content">
        <TextView 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:id="@+id/tvdebug" android:text="Debug" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
        <com.blueproject.BlueProject.WaveFormView
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/surfaceView1"/> 
    </LinearLayout>

Comment: What is the name of the file where `WaveFormView` is declared?

Comment: now it says:
The following classes could not be instantiated:

Comment: Then it should be `com.blueproject.BlueProject$WaveFormView` (note the `$` sign...)

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.blueproject.BlueProject$WaveFormView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.instantiateClass(Unknown Source)
 at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.ProjectCallback.loadView(Unknown Source)

Comment: Add `public static` to your class name - `public static class WaveFormView`

Comment: didn't work either :s the static makes me buch of errors appear in the class

Comment: Could you upload the full class code to a site like this: http://codeviewer.org/upload and share the link to it with us?

Comment: You do a non-trivial thing by using members of your class in your view instead of passing them, but I think the following will help: change `<com.blueproject.BlueProject.WaveFormView ` to `<view class="com.blueproject.BlueProject.WaveFormView"` (and use `public`, not `public static`)

Comment: No, says:
attempted  duplicate class definition for name: "com/blueproject/BlueProject$WaveFormView"

Comment: I always got the same error after cleaning the project:
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.blueproject.BlueProject.WaveFormView

Comment: We could've continue with this thread, but it's kind of hard this way. I think you should separate the view and put it in a different file as a separate class, and pass the relevant fields by some method. The current implemented way binds the view to the activity to hard, and this might cause the problem. please consider that.

Comment: Seperate class in different files WORKED! Thank you very much ! I've been working on it for a week !

Comment: Glad it helped. I think this is a better practice anyway :)